# Javascript Asynchronous Scoping Issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to implement some flow control of async ajax calls. My project receives basically an array of values then completes an ajax call for each of them, process the results then run a function when complete.

I have a scoping issue in that the flow control function when initiated a 2nd time with a different array of work to complete its job reference value is overwritten. I have rewritten just the part I have trouble with eliminating all the other functions and posted it on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/qanx9/

When the code is initiated the jobRunner function will console log the key to the globalObj where work is found. On the 3rd run of the function job2 is lost and everything is now referring to job1. I have tried putting everything inside this function in an anonymous function but that made no difference.

This is my first attempt at flow control and my project is actually in nodejs. There are libraries that do this for me but I am trying to get a good understanding on how this works.

```
// global used to track async flow control and store completed work
globalObj = {
    job1: {
        work: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10],
        results: []
    },
    job2: {
        work: [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
        results: []
    },
    async: {
        limit: 5,
        running: 0
    }
};

// flow control
function jobRunner(job) {
    console.log(job)
    g = globalObj.async;
    j = globalObj[job]; 
    while (g.running < g.limit && j.work.length > 0) {
        var task = j.work.shift();
        fakeAsyncAjax(task,function(result){
            j.results.push(result);
            g.running--;
            if (j.work.length > 0) {
                jobRunner(job);
            } else if (g.running == 0) {
                jobDone(job);
            }
        })
        g.running++;
    }
}

function jobDone(job) {
    console.log(job+' complete..');
}

// instead of doing real ajax calls here ive done a basic simulation with a random delay, using setTimeout to make it async.
function fakeAsyncAjax(ref,completeFunc){
    setTimeout(function(){
        completeFunc(ref);
    },Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1))
}

// initate jobs
jobRunner('job1')
jobRunner('job2')
```

Comment: `g` and `j` are global variables!!! While it doesn't matter for `g`, it does for `j`!

Comment: Notice that the `results` will be in random order, because you just `push` to them when one of the running jobs has finished. They're not in the same order as the `work`.

Comment: Doesn't matter on the order the results are returned. Im using taffydb to then query the results on client side. Ill try removing globals.

Comment: Here it is updated globalObj is only now used to track the async requests. The work is now passed into the jobRunner function. Updated here http://jsfiddle.net/qanx9/1/ but still getting the same result in the console.

Comment: A `jobRunner` that is called when `g.running >= g.limit` (such as your invocation `jobRunner('job2')`) does not do anything, but is completely ignored. You will need to implement a queue to store those, letting them wait until the number of running jobs decreases below the limit.

Comment: Also, in the function in your fiddle the `results` are no more global, but get recreated on every time a `jobRunner` is invoked (even if he will only run a single task)